# Chrome, Firefox and any web browser blocking specific sites

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, browser, html, console

I've been having this trouble for quite some time now, it happens only with Dribble.

Every time I try to connect, a HTML only appears. When I open the Inspect tab, this is the first error that comes in:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

I've tried disabling and uninstalling my Adblock, which was Ublock, clearing cookies and cache but nothing seems to work.

Every other computer connected in the same WiFi works just fine.

Some screen shots:

[image: What it looks like]

[image: Console]